# How to unload C++ DLL in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c++

I load a C++ DLL using DLLImport in my C# ASP.Net web application. The DLL basically reads some CSV files, and manipulates them and creates new files.

After I ran the method successfully, and run it again then I get C++ exception back.

I want to unload the C++ DLL from the website so a user can re- load the DLL and re run the method.  Do you know how to either eliminate this error or get rid of this error message so the DLL can be unloaded after its run?

Comment: it says [SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception.] Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: External component has thrown an exception.

Comment: Put C++ code here. Maybe there is some memory leak or problem in logic of it! You don't need to unload any `DLL` from memory, because `DLL` files  could be in access from multiple application in same time.

Comment: the code is huge. basically i have global variables in which I am loading CSV files, i am reading three CSV files, taking some values from few columns, doing some calculations and writing the data in another file.  I am hoping that class level variables must be deleted from memory and csv files must be released after their scope (i.e. after last bracket of class?)

Comment: Maybe [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/clr/thread/94bcae24-864c-4672-8778-e7bcd8cef90f) help.

Comment: i am using C++ cplex to read csv files but after i read them, i am not closing or releasing the files. do you know how to release files in c++ cplex IloCsvReader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there's no way to do late binding with C#.

You can do it by creating a C++ DLL and using that, however. Assuming you know enough about C++ to do this, you would just need a single function exported by the DLL, which uses `LoadLibrary` to load your CSV manipulation DLL, `GetProcAddress` to retrieve the address of the function you want to call, and then `FreeLibrary` to release the library.

An example would be something like:

```
extern "C" {
  __declspec(dllexport) bool InvokeMyFunction() {
    HMODULE lib = LoadLibrary("csvlib.dll");
    if (!lib)
      return false;

    void (*func)(int) = (void (*)(int))GetProcAddress(lib, "MyCsvFunc");
    if (!func)
      return false;

    func(5);

    FreeLibrary(lib);

    return true;
  }
}
```

This isn't completely safe, though. If possible, it's better to find out what the problem with your DLL function being called more than once is, and fixing it.

Comment: if C++ locks a file during its process and if I call FreeLibrary method, will it also release the locked files along with freeing the C++ DLL?

Comment: Not necessarily. Only if the unloading code in dll explicitly closes the filehandles.

Comment: My initial guess would be that it doesn't release any resources; it's possible that the DLL could have passed a handle back to the loader. I'm not completely sure, though. Someone might know better.

Comment: you mean i need to add a destructor and add releasing of code there?

Answer (score 1):

If it's your code... why not just provide a `FreeResources` function?

As an alternative, fixing your code to make your function re-entrant would also work.

Answer (score 0):

According to my information, the unmanaged DLL is always loaded into the main app domain. If it weren't, you would be able to unload the DLL in that way.

Since this is problematic at best, I'd like to propose a different solution: Why not write a separate command line program which does the work and run that as needed. It would run in it's own process and be completely unloaded after running.

Comment: so you're suggesting that I should call the method of the C++ Dll in a .bat file?  or should I convert the DLL into .exe and then call the method?

Comment: I meant that you would write a small command line C# program in your solution that does nothing more than call that unmanaged function. This isn't optimal but would be a pretty cheap quick fix.

You would need to give the ASP.NET process access to this exe file and deploy it with the web application.

Comment: good idea. how would i pass input parameters to the function?

Comment: You could pass in parameters to that command line program by creating a [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) object and run it with arguments (see the example in the link). Then in that command line program you would pass parameters to the function directly from the command line parameters.